# Align UITabBarItem image to the left and to the right

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBar` with 3 items.

Each item has just an image (without a text).

What happens now is that all of the three images are presented in the center of each `tabBarItem.

What I want to accomplish is that the left `UITabBarItem`'s image will be aligned to the left. The middle `UITabBarItem`'s image will stay in the center, and the right `UITabBarItem` will be aligned to the right.

I've searched all over the internet a way, but `UITabBarItem` doesn't have any `alignImage` property or something like that.

Any idea how can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> Set image inset of tab bar item like this

Comment: Worked when the values were `30` and `-30`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying horizontal value of "Custom offset" for UITabBarItem in Storyboard as per screenshot. (Note: give positive value for right TabBarItem to the right, negative value for left one and "Default position" for center one)

[image]

In device, it will look like as below:

[image]

Comment: And if I'm not using storyboard? How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: Get the UITabBarItem instance from view controller and use "titlePositionAdjustment: UIOffset" method to provide offset value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Basically you could set the insets of the `image` property on your tabBarButton(`UITabBarItem`). There could be another way but give a try.

```
let tabBarButton = UITabBarItem.init(title: "One", image: myImage, selectedImage: nil)
tabBarButton.image?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0))//Give your left alignment number

//one more way
tabBarButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0)
```